# 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded' in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel-4, utf-8

I'm using Laravel (a PHP framework) to write a service for mobile and have the data returned in `JSON` format. In the data result there are some fields encoded in `UTF-8`.

The following statement

```
return JsonResponse::create($data);
```

returns the error below

```
InvalidArgumentException
HELP
Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Open: /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.php
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            restore_error_handler();

            throw $exception;
        }

        if (JSON_ERROR_NONE !== json_last_error()) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException($this->transformJsonError());
        }
```

I've changed:

```
return JsonResponse::create($data);
```

to

```
return JsonResponse::create($data, 200, array('Content-Type'=>'application/json; charset=utf-8' ));
```

but it still isn't working.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is `$data`? Where does it come from, what's in it, how do you know it's UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: $data is array data from database.
I checked $data, it have a string "兆琪" => error when return json.

Comment: It fixed, it is my error. Have a line code not good:

substr('兆琪', ...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 98):

I found the answer to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305169/php-json-encode-malformed-utf-8-characters-possibly-incorrectly-encoded)

Just do

```
mb_convert_encoding($data['name'], 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution work. I wrap one of the array returned with this function and regenerate json using json_encode and all works.

Comment: I am trying to convert a Turkish keyword into UTF-8 but it does not work with ajax request in laravel framework according to your solution. Thanks dear.

Comment: This worked for me. But can anyone explain why? I mean converting from utf8 to utf8 seems like doing nothing from the outside

Answer (score 94):

I wrote this method to handle UTF8 arrays and JSON objects as well. It works fine with array (simple and multidimensional) and will recursively convert everything from latin1 (ISO-8859-1) to UTF-8;

```
/**
 * Encode array from latin1 to utf8 recursively
 * @param $dat
 * @return array|string
 */
   public static function convert_from_latin1_to_utf8_recursively($dat)
   {
      if (is_string($dat)) {
         return utf8_encode($dat);
      } elseif (is_array($dat)) {
         $ret = [];
         foreach ($dat as $i => $d) $ret[ $i ] = self::convert_from_latin1_to_utf8_recursively($d);
         return $ret;
      } elseif (is_object($dat)) {
         foreach ($dat as $i => $d) $dat->$i = self::convert_from_latin1_to_utf8_recursively($d);
         return $dat;
      } else {
         return $dat;
      }
   }
```

Following is a sample on how to use it:

```
// Just pass your array or string and the UTF8 encode will be fixed
$data = convert_from_latin1_to_utf8_recursively($data);
```

**Updated at June 2023.**

`utf8_encode()` was deprecated in **PHP 8.2**, so use `mb_convert_encoding()` on newer versions.

So, replace `utf8_encode($dat)` for `mb_convert_encoding($dat, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8')`

Additionally, note that `ini_set('default_charset', 'ISO-8859-1')`   may change the behavior of the `mb_convert_encoding` method.

Comment: The else keyword is not needed if you have a return in the previous block.

Comment: @Vladimir Nul please do not edit the code inside the original question **even if it's not having effects on the overall result of the snippet**. Thank you

Comment: Worked for me on Laravel 5.6 and DB2 AS/400. Thanks!

Comment: @Tiago Gouvea -  Your solution is not working for me. Your function is converting a turkish keyword 'Ücretsiz' to 'Ãcretsiz' which is not solving any type of problem. Thanks.

Comment: Note that utf8_encode() was deprecated in PHP 8.2, use mb_convert_encoding() instead.

Comment: tks, meu php 7.4 was perfect !

Answer (score 9):

In my case I had a `ucfirst` on the asian letters string. This was not possible and produced a non utf8 string.

Comment: been searching for ages this solved my problem

Answer (score 8):

In Laravel 7.x,  this helped me to get rid of this error.

```
$newString = mb_convert_encoding($arr, "UTF-8", "auto");
return response()->json($newString);
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it turns characters like "ó" to "?"

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this causes error:

```
return response->json(["message" => "Model status successfully updated!", "data" => $model], 200);
```

but this not:

```
return response->json(["message" => "Model status successfully updated!", "data" => $model->toJson()], 200);
```

Answer (score 4):

I know it's already an old question, but i had the same error today. For me setting the connection variable on model did the work.

```
/**
 * Table properties
 */
protected $connection = 'mysql-utf8';
protected $table = 'notification';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
```

I don't know if the issue was with the database (probably), but the texts fields with special chars (like ~, ´ e etc) were all messed up.

**---- Editing**

That $connection var is used to select wich db connection your model will use. Sometimes it happens that in database.php (under /config folder) you have multiples connections and the default one is not using UTF-8 charset.

In any case, be sure to properly use charset and collation into your connection.

```
'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'your_database'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'database_password'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null
    ],

    'mysql-utf8' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'your_database'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'database_password'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null
    ],
```

Comment: Unsupported driver [mysql-utf8]

Comment: Here you are setting a connection (a database) where I guess you are trying to set a special config to the database. This won't work (unless you have a db connection with that name).

Comment: Yeah you right. Improved the answer, hope it helps someone.

Comment: These config things really helped me! Thanks!

Comment: still relevant in 2022. great answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced the same problem. The thing is that I forgot to start the apache and mysql in xampp... :S

Answer (score 3):

For more solution i have completed the solution of (the great) Tiago Gouvêa exposed before only for strings and arrays

i used md_convert_encoding() function instead of utf8_encode(), it works for me : (12 hours loosed ...)

// this object return me a big array who have multiple arrays imbricated

```
$get_days = program::get_days($ARR, $client);
```

// and i use this function for well parsing what the server return *

```
function convert_to_utf8_recursively($dat){
    if( is_string($dat) ){
        return mb_convert_encoding($dat, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
    }
    elseif( is_array($dat) ){
        $ret = [];
        foreach($dat as $i => $d){
            $ret[$i] = convert_to_utf8_recursively($d);
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    else{
        return $dat;
    }
}
                
// use 
$data = convert_to_utf8_recursively($get_days);
```

- what the server return *
  i talk to that because i test the same code in two different servers
  the first return me a well formatted json , without any function, as we usually do BUT the second server does not send me back anything if I do not apply this function ...

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer here.

The solution turned out to be in my application code, it has nothing to do with Laravel itself.

```
return mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($this->first_name, 0, 1) . mb_substr($this->last_name, 0, 1));
```

https://barryvanveen.nl/blog/67-solving-malformed-utf-8-characters-possibly-incorrectly-encoded-error-in-laravel

Comment: I had a similar issue. In short, using a non multi-byte function, such as `substr` on a UTF-8 string was incorrect. I had to use the multi-byte version instead, `mb_substr`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case one of the MySql columns was of type `POINT` which the json parser could not parse. After excluding the column or adding the relevant model accessor, solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it happened twice:

1. I forgot to migrate again. I roll back (`php artisan rollback`) the latest migration operation because I want to change something on my database schema but I forgot to execute again the migrate command: `php artisan migrate`.

More info on migrations:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations

2. It also happened to me when the API is returning JSON responses with attributes of type `blob` (column on the database that is created with the `binary()` method). For my use case, I hide that attribute by adding the attribute's name to the model's array property `$hidden`. It works fine after that.

More info on hiding attributes on JSON:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
function convertToUtf8($data) {
    if (is_string($data)) return mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
    if (is_array($data)) return array_map('convertToUtf8', $data);
    if (is_object($data)) foreach ($data as $i => $datum) $data->$i = convertToUtf8($datum);
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is for 8 years ago and laravel had a lot of changes during. As other people explained you should rectify config/databse.php. But the lastest varsion of laravel, the charset is set 'utf8mb4' therefor no need if you are used install new laravel versions. I think you have more than 1 db. Perhaps you have forgotten to change the charset in your config/databse.php. In my case i had several databases and i forgot to add to my second db 'mysql..' Add this to the file.

```
        'mysql2 or whatever' => [

/// ... the rest
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
///...
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and i fixed the issue with `iconv` function like following:

```
iconv('latin5', 'utf-8', $data['index']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my problem and this is how I solved it, hope it works for someone else.

Make sure the encoding of the file is UTF-8, in vscode is in the right bottom part.

[image: Encoding position in vscode]

I had this particular problem when I modified a file that already was in a development server, somehow the encoding when I edited that file in that server was changed to ANSI, so, make sure too that your file is encoded in UTF-8 in the server where you are doing your deployments.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was using

```
strtoupper(substr($user->name, 0, 2))
```

so i used

```
mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($user->name, 0, 2))
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the charset at after you made the connection to db like

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if (!$conn->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $conn->error);
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $conn->character_set_name());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution.  This fixed it for me.  Apparently the MySQL database in our project is returning the data with a different charset.  Of course I removed the ELSE line at the end of your suggested code.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same issue. However, in my case I had the column in the table specified as varchar(255) and my content was larger when I was doing inserts. So it used to truncate the part which could not fit in the varchar column size.

To fix this, I updated my column type to longtext so larger text can be stored. Also, added a frontend validation to not have text larger than the column. (I was using this to store draft js escaped HTML)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the error was similar to what @dev1234 mentioned here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71279140/7880201) as part of the suggested answers.

But the problem was as a result of laravel outputing the entire error which contained blob(s). I would advise you do not return just the error message in the case of

```
try {
} catch (\Throwable $th) {

    // $code = $th->getCode();
    $msg = $th->getMessage();
    // dd($msg);
    abort(404, 'THERE WAS AN ERROR: ' . $msg);

}
```

So to rectify this issue, just show a little friendly error even if you want to show it to yourself alone as a dev.

Check all blobs to ensure that laravel is not just outputing them from the ajax response and you will be fine.

I hope it saves you today. If not, there are still good answers to try. :)