# PHP json encode - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Tags: php, json, encoding, utf-8

I'm using `json_encode($data)` to an data array and there's a field contains Russian characters.

I used this `mb_detect_encoding()` to display what encoding it is for that field and it displays UTF-8.

I think the json encode failed due to some bad characters in it like "ра▒". I tried alot of things `utf8_encode` on the data and it will by pass that error but then the data doesn't look correct anymore.

What can be done with this issue?

Comment: *I tried alot of things* - Like what? Please show us your code/research.

Comment: Have you tried the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option?

Comment: Tried "JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE" already. Not work.

Comment: I tried other things and either will return the same error or the character totally changed something not readable.

Comment: `utf8_encode()` is for converting 8859-1 to UTF8, and feeding it a UTF8 string will *corrupt* it.

Answer (score 112):

The issue happens if there are some non-utf8 characters inside even though most of them are utf8 chars. This will remove any non-utf8 characters and now it works.

```
$data['name'] = mb_convert_encoding($data['name'], 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: You might want to add this as well `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");`

Comment: I've tried to find that invalid string by adding the following code:
`
foreach ($addresses as $address) {
            $converted = mb_convert_encoding($address, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
            if ($converted !== $address) {
                dd($addresses);
            }
}`

Two points:

1. The `$converted !== $address` condition is never met. I suppose this is because `===` is a "binary-safe" operator…

2. I don't get error in the end, even though I never assign `$converted` to anything! It's like `mb_convert_encoding()` accepted string by reference, although it's not…

Comment: Funny also because of the bad encoding, both functions `mb_check_encoding()` and `json_decode()` didn't work properly.. And `mb_detect_encoding()` did..It was a problem with bad UTF-8 encoded file.. But after `mb_convert_encoding()`, everything worked as expected..

Answer (score 48):

If you have a multidimensional array to encode in JSON format then you can use below function:

**If JSON_ERROR_UTF8 occurred :**

```
$encoded = json_encode( utf8ize( $responseForJS ) );
```

**Below function is used to encode Array data recursively**

```
/* Use it for json_encode some corrupt UTF-8 chars
 * useful for = malformed utf-8 characters possibly incorrectly encoded by json_encode
 */
function utf8ize( $mixed ) {
    if (is_array($mixed)) {
        foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) {
            $mixed[$key] = utf8ize($value);
        }
    } elseif (is_string($mixed)) {
        return mb_convert_encoding($mixed, "UTF-8", "UTF-8");
    }
    return $mixed;
}
```

Comment: `mb_convert_encoding` does the recursive work itself, as you can see in the documentation [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php): _If val is an array, all its string values will be converted recursively._ So the function `utf8ize` is not needed. All you need would be `json_encode(mb_convert_encoding($responseForJS, "UTF-8", "UTF-8"));`

Comment: mb_convert_encoding is only able to convert arrays if you are running PHP 7.2 or above, just for clarification. Otherwise, this function works perfectly.

Answer (score 34):

With php 7.2, two options allow to manage invalid UTF-8 direcly in json_encode :

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode

```
json_encode($text, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE);
```

Or

```
json_encode($text, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE);
```

Comment: thanks, It works for me because my response in api has emoji in title string, but i have one confusion, that i have read somewhere that emoji is utf-8 character then why emoji in string gives this malformed utf-8 characters error?

Comment: @HaritsinhGohil perhaps some emojis are valid UTF-8 chars and others are not ...

Answer (score 28):

Please, make sure to initiate your Pdo object with the charset iso as utf8.
This should fix this problem avoiding any re-utf8izing dance.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mybase;charset=utf8", 'user', 'password');
```

Comment: This solved my situation. It also works for other connection types, like dlib for MSSQL Server.

Comment: Was given an old project to fix encoding issues and this helped me a lot. Only difference is that this project was using ADO and solution was a little bit different, solved it by using setCharset(), info here http://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:reference:connection:setcharset

Answer (score 9):

you just add in your pdo connection **charset=utf8**
like below line of pdo connection:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mybase;charset=utf8", 'user', 'password');
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 3):

Remove HTML entities before JSON encoding. I used `html_entity_decode()` in PHP and the problem was solved

```
$json = html_entity_decode($source);
$data = json_decode($json,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is well encoded in the database for example, make sure to use the mb_ * functions for string handling, before json_encode. Functions like substr or strlen do not work well with utf8mb4 and can cut your text and leave a malformed UTF8

Answer (score 0):

Do you by any chance have UUIDs in your result set? In that case the following database flag will help:

```
PDO::DBLIB_ATTR_STRINGIFY_UNIQUEIDENTIFIER => true
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is kind of an old topic, but for me it was what I needed. I just needed to modify the answer 'jayashan perera'.

```
//...code
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($result) ; $i++) { 
            $tempCnpj = $result[$i]['CNPJ'];
            $tempFornecedor = json_encode(html_entity_decode($result[$i]['Nome_fornecedor']),true) ;
            $tempData = $result[$i]['efetivado_data'];
            $tempNota = $result[$i]['valor_nota'];
            $arrResposta[$i] = ["Status"=>"true", "Cnpj"=>"$tempCnpj", "Fornecedor"=>$tempFornecedor, "Data"=>"$tempData", "Nota"=>"$tempNota" ];
        }

        echo json_encode($arrResposta);
```

And no .js i have use

```
obj = JSON.parse(msg);
```