# Malformed JSON from GET request

Tags: php, json, regex, laravel, get

I am having some problems with fetching a JSON file using `HTTP:retry` (or any of the other methods). The JSON file ends up looking like the picture below when I do `->body();` and then `dd()` it:

[image: dd() of get result]

I have attempted to do some cleaning with preg_replace (but not so good at regex), seems to partially work:

```
preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $data );
```

Because the JSON looks like this it is not possible to do `->json();` it just returns `null` when I then `dd()` it. How can I can "clean" this properly so the result can be accessed as a normal JSON file?

Here is the output in text (missing the newlines (\n):

```
b"""
{
"devname":"Event Telt",
"devsn":"18940256",
"time":"14:54:53 2020-07-18",
"timeunix":"1595084093",
"synch":"1",
"ch1":
{
 "name":"Temp Dataskap",
 "unit":"°C",
 "aval":"19.1",
 "alarm":0
},
"ch2":
{
 "name":"Temp Rom",
 "unit":"°C",
 "aval":"17.4",
 "alarm":0
},
"ch3":
{
 "name":"Fukt Rom",
 "unit":"%RH",
 "aval":"77.0",
 "alarm":1
},
"ch4":
{
 "name":"Channel 4",
 "unit":"",
 "aval":"n/a",
 "alarm":0
},
"ch5":
{
 "name":"Channel 5",
 "unit":"",
 "aval":"n/a",
 "alarm":0
}
}
"""
```

Comment: Can you show the output as text rather than an image as it's easier for others to work with.

Comment: Sure thing @NigelRen, have been added. Though it misses the newlines (\n), that the image shows. Thanks for any suggestions for a fix

Comment: Not sure if it's `dd()`, but there seem to be extra `"` at the start and end, try `trim('"', $json)` (ideally fix the problem at source if this is the case).

Comment: perhaps sharing the code used to generate this output would be useful?

Comment: This output is generated by a external program that i have no control over @ProfessorAbronsius, sadly the trim that was suggested did not make a change...

Comment: Perhaps try `preg_replace('/^b"""[\r\n]*(.*)"""/s', '$1', $data);`

Comment: Thank you to everyone for suggestions. I was able to find a solution and have posted it as a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem finally solved,

It seems like the problem was malformed UTF-8 or something (See this answer: [PHP json encode - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305169/php-json-encode-malformed-utf-8-characters-possibly-incorrectly-encoded))

It was fixed with this simple oneliner: `mb_convert_encoding($temps->body(), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8')`.

It seems like the special chars and weird addons in the dump was a side effect of how laravel displays stuff after a `dd()`

Thank you everyone for your suggestions!