# PHP - converting data from MariaDB to JSON - � wrong encoding

Tags: php, pdo, character-encoding, mariadb

I seem to have some problem with encoding, but I can't pinpoint it.

PHPMyAdmin says:

```
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.3.39-MariaDB-log - MariaDB Server
Server charset: ISO 8859-2 Central European (latin2)
Server connection collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I can't change the SQL server in any way, this is provided by my website hosting provider.

All my dbs, tables and columns use `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. All files are encoded as `UTF-8`. The values display properly both in PHPMyAdmin and in MySQLWorkbench. Other scripts on my website work fine, displaying english, russian, chinese, etc. Just this one is not complying for some reason. I tried inserting the data through PHPMA, Workbench, and even from the very same script.

I connect using PDO, with charset specified, via an included file:

```
<?php
if (!isset($pdo))
{
    $DBHOST = 'localhost';
    $DBNAME = '***';
    $DBUSER = '***';
    $DBPASS = '***';
    $DBCHRS = 'utf8mb4';

    $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$DBHOST.';dbname='.$DBNAME.';charset='.$DBCHRS;
    $options = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => false];
    try
    {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $DBUSER, $DBPASS, $options);
    }
    catch (\PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'Could not connect to the database!<br>Message: ', $e->getMessage(), '<br>Code: ', $e->getCode();
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

and then

```
$json = [];
$json['people'] = [];
$json['relations'] = [];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `tree_people`;');
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    $json['people'][] = $row;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `tree_relations`;');
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    $json['relations'][] = $row;

/*/
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
/*/
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//*/

//*/
echo '<pre>';
print_r($json);
echo '</pre>';
//*/

echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo '</pre>';
```

JSON fails to generate (empty string?) and the content displayed with `print_r` has all the special characters showing as �.

I'm going crazy, what is going on?

Edit: I can properly read data from other tables. However it is only possible when I write the data to the DB through my own editor, not through PMA. See https://herhor.net/news/?id=1 when I first inserted it via PMA, it was full of unknown characters.
However, now when I read it in PMA or Workbench, it is full of scrambled characters.

It seems that there is some mismatch between the encoding used by PMA/Workbench and the one used by all my scripts. Shouldn't the DB deal with it automatically?

Edit2:
As requested, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` for Workbench:

```
character_set_client    utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8mb4
character_set_server    latin2
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

For PMA:

```
character_set_client    utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8mb4
character_set_server    latin2
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

For PHP PDO:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Variable_name] => character_set_client
            [Value] => latin2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Variable_name] => character_set_connection
            [Value] => latin2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Variable_name] => character_set_database
            [Value] => utf8mb4
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Variable_name] => character_set_filesystem
            [Value] => binary
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Variable_name] => character_set_results
            [Value] => latin2
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Variable_name] => character_set_server
            [Value] => latin2
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Variable_name] => character_set_system
            [Value] => utf8
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Variable_name] => character_sets_dir
            [Value] => /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
        )

)
```

Also here is the SQL import/export file for both tables: https://pastebin.com/33Ap4Vje

Comment: It seems you did quite a thorough job. I don't get what you say: No JSON output from `json_encode()`, yet you can see output with `print_r()`. That doesn't make sense to me. Could you have a look at what [json_last_error_msg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) reports? Also, and this is not really that important, calling a variable `$json` when it clearly isn't JSON is weird, and variable names should be semantic, something like `$trees`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware as expected. `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`

Comment: Well, that's not what I expected, but it is useful information.

Comment: As for the latter part, yeah, it should be named "to_be_json" or "my_object" or something.
And well, of course I did as thorough of a job as possible; SO likes to skin alive people who dont :P

Comment: Try to reduce the problem. First get rid of the database stuff, use `var_export()` instead of `print_r()` to create the data you want to `json_encode()`. Then you can find the offending character.

Comment: @user3783243 It's the server, not the database, and that's not a problem. Mine is using `cp1252 West European (latin1)`. Note that the "charset" in the database connection here is UTF-8.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I'm not sure what you are suggesting? `var_export` also shows U+FFFD. I'm convinced the problem is with mysql, not with the json module itself. If it receives malformed input, of course it will break. The point is, I have no idea what can be wrong with mysql, if it works properly everywhere else.

Comment: My problem is that I don't have your database, so I like to get rid of it by reducing the problem to a simple input string of bytes. The U+FFFD or � is your browser covering something up it cannot decode given the character encoding. Are you sure the PHP file you're running is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: There are some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305169/php-json-encode-malformed-utf-8-characters-possibly-incorrectly-encoded) that might help

Comment: Please check (and confirm by adding to your question) the output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE \'char%\';` in Workbench, PMA and your PHP script (`print_r($pdo->query('SHOW VARIABLES LIKE \'char%\'')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));`). Also the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tree_relations;`. I know you have already stated that they are all utf8mb4, but this is clearly not the case, as if it was uft-8 all the way through with no implicit or explicit charset conversion, this would not be happening.

Comment: @user1191247 seems like you nailed it. In PHP, the result charset is latin2 for some reason.

Comment: @user1191247 I use the same connection code everywhere, so even if it was included multiple times, it should have no effect.

Comment: @user1191247 Sure, put it inside the try block, nothing changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255985/discussion-between-user1191247-and-herhor67).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your edit shows, the problem is definitely with the PDO connection as it is showing `latin2` in the various `character_set_*` variables.

Does adding `SET NAMES utf8mb4` to your `$options` array help:

```php
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
];
```

Comment: Thanks! The connection charset finally changed to `utf8mb4` and the contents are now the same in Workbench, PMA and in the scripts. For some reason, the charset specified during connection was ignored...

Comment: I am glad this is working for you, but it still doesn't feel like an answer, as the code you posted should work. I cannot figure out why the charset in the dsn is not working 

Comment: @herhor67 I have not been able to replicate this issue. Please would you check the Client API version shown for pdo_mysql in phpinfo?

Comment: PHPInfo shows `mysqlnd 8.1.25` under `pdo_mysql`

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better if you provided the exact string you're having trouble with, but I'm guessing you're dealing with Non-UTF8 data. `json_encode()` in PHP will return empty string if it gets characters (bytes) outside UTF8 range I guess. Try to re-encode your string before passing it to `json_encode()`.

You can use `utf8_encode()` on your string, or in case your string is encoded with Windows-1252/ANSI you can use the following approach:

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6607083/11972382), which specifically discusses this problem on PDO:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  foreach($row as &$value)
  {
    $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");
  }
  unset($value);
  $json['relations'][] = $row;
}
```

---

**Update:**
According to your update, seems that your data was scrambled in the first place (When you inserted that using PHPMYADMIN), but if it is working properly when using website editor (Which works with PDO right?), problem might be caused by `charset collation` set in your DB, One possible solution is to:

- Export your DB as a `.sql` file
- Read the file till you find `charset collation` and make sure it is `utf8_general_ci` and your data is ok(not messed up by encoding), save the file and add it as a new DB and use that one.
- Make sure to use `SET NAMES UTF8` query every time you interact with your DB, like in PDO you can use something like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9982219/11972382).

[This good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779380/11972382) might help you too.

Comment: My strings are names/surnames, which contain polish characters, like `ł`, `ą`, `ś`, `ć` etc

Comment: Converting from UTF-8 to UTF-8 just replaces U+FFFD with `?`. Converting from Windows-1252 fixes like literally one of the characters, but the rest are still wrong.

Comment: `var_dump( json_encode("łąść") );` seems to be working fine with the result of `string(26) ""\u0142\u0105\u015b\u0107""` , Can you send a dump of base64-encoded binary of your string? Use sth like `base64_encode(implode(' ',$json));` and add the result to your question, then we can test that string for encoding. @herhor67

Comment: Please see edit. It seems that there is some mismatch between the encoding used by PHPMA/Workbench and the one used by all my scripts.

Comment: Please see the update on answer @herhor67

Comment: Why should I use UTF8 instead of utf8mb4?

Comment: No reasons, `utf8mb4` is even better, can store up to 4 bytes. You haven't mentioned encoding at first, so I thought you might be on ASCII (`latin1`). @herhor67

Comment: I think that using `utf8mb4_*` collation makes it obvious I have `utf8mb4` charset. Or if not, sorry then.