# possibly incorrectly encoded,Malformed UTF-8 characters

Tags: php, json, laravel, utf-8

I am trying to fetch the records in laravel then it will give me following error.

**Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded**

This is my code

```
$Login = DB::table('usermaster')

        ->where('Email', $uname)

        ->where('Password', md5($password))

        ->get();

    return response()->json($Login);
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115982/malformed-utf-8-characters-possibly-incorrectly-encoded-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my laravel query i am use a following code so it will give a this type of error...

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

```
$BvoData = DB::table('test1')->select('test1.*')
        ->where("test1.Id", "".$id."")
        ->first();

$BvoData->temp1 = DB::table('temp1')->where('tmpdata', $BvoData->tmpdata)->get(); 

$BvoData->temp2 = DB::table('temp2')->where('Id', $id)->get();

return response()->json($BvoData);
```

but i will solve this error by doing following code...

```
$BvoData = DB::table('test1')->select('test1.*')
        ->where("test1.Id", "".$id."")
        ->first();

$BvoData = (array)  $BvoData;

$BvoData->temp1 = DB::table('temp1')->where('tmpdata', $BvoData->tmpdata)->get(); 

$BvoData["temp1"] = json_decode(json_encode($BvoData["temp1"]), True);


$BvoData->temp2 = DB::table('temp2')->where('Id', $id)->get();

$BvoData["temp2"] = json_decode(json_encode($BvoData["temp2"]), True);

return response()->json($BvoData);
```

by using json_decode and json_encode i solve my problem...

Comment: This solution did not work for me, still getting ""message": "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"," error. Thanks.