# laravel sql error on server, `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded` error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9

My laravel app is working fine on Postman locally and returning what I want, when I upload to the server and test using postman I get this message

`InvalidArgumentException: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded in file`

Both MySQL are running using `utf-8` collation
my `config/database.php` says:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => 'InnoDB',
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

any ideas would be appreciated
**Edit: the error trace is as follows:**

```
InvalidArgumentException: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded in file /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php on line 61
#0 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(35): Illuminate\Http\Response-&gt;setContent()
#1 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php(57): Illuminate\Http\Response-&gt;__construct()
#2 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(724): Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory-&gt;make()
#3 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php(22): response()
#4 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\Http\Controllers\OrderController-&gt;showOrders()
#5 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\Routing\Controller-&gt;callAction()
#6 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(261): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher-&gt;dispatch()
#7 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(204): Illuminate\Routing\Route-&gt;runController()
#8 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(725): Illuminate\Routing\Route-&gt;run()
#9 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#10 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#11 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings-&gt;handle()
#12 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(126): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#13 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests-&gt;handleRequest()
#14 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(54): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests-&gt;handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter()
#15 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests-&gt;handle()
#16 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/Http/Middleware/EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#17 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful-&gt;Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\{closure}()
#18 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#19 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/Http/Middleware/EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php(34): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then()
#20 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful-&gt;handle()
#21 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#22 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(727): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then()
#23 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(702): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRouteWithinStack()
#24 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(666): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRoute()
#25 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(655): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatchToRoute()
#26 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(167): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatch()
#27 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}()
#28 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#29 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle()
#30 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull-&gt;handle()
#31 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#32 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle()
#33 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings-&gt;handle()
#34 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#35 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize-&gt;handle()
#36 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#37 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance-&gt;handle()
#38 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#39 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors-&gt;handle()
#40 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#41 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies-&gt;handle()
#42 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#43 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(142): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then()
#44 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(111): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;sendRequestThroughRouter()
#45 /home/woodemmj/shopping-spree.woodsowl.net/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;handle()
#46 {main}
```

code:

```
public function showOrders()
    {
        $orders = Order::where('customer_id', auth()->guard('customers')->user()->id)->orderByDesc('created_at')->get();
        return response();
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the  trace here?

Comment: the trace is ? sorry I'm a bit new @SachinBahukhandi

Comment: Can you post the entire error?

Comment: I added it as an edit @SachinBahukhandi

Comment: As it looks in the response it is most probably generated in the response.Did you try?https://stackoverflow.com/a/49564258/5192105

Comment: then why is it working on local? the response is fairly simple and has no none utf8 chars

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247104/discussion-between-sachin-bahukhandi-and-omar-malas).

Comment: What is line 51?  What is the hex of the naughty characters?

Answer (score 0):

based on the code snippet mentioned the solution should be:

```
return response()->json($orders);
```

or

```
$orders->toJson();
return $orders
```

Comment: not using any of what you said, I'm only making a query, ordering the result, and sending it as a response

Comment: can you post your code snippet that using this query? for more understanding about what you're doing.

Comment: added to original post

Comment: Ok you can try, return response()->json($orders); or $order->toJson(); then return $orders instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).